# How to pass method as Action parameter

Tags: vb.net

How can i pass parameter to method as statement.  I have a method like this
I try to stimulate ternary operator in C# to vb.net without using IIF keyword

```
Protected Friend Sub TernaryOperater(ByVal condition As Boolean, _
   ByVal truePart As action, Optional ByVal falsePart As action = Nothing)
  If condition Then
      truePart()
  Else
      falsePart()
  End If
End Sub
```

and i call this method like this:

```
TernaryOperater(DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0, _
    tp21txtBillNo.Clear, tp21txtBillNo.focus)
```

It's shown red error color under statement `tp21txtBillNo.clear` and `tp21txtBillNo.focus`.  Is `Action` not supported in  statements like this?

(Looking for both C# and VB.Net variants)

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: BTW this already exists in VB.NET, it's the `Iif` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx VB2008 also introduces the short-circuiting `If(c,t,f)` operator which works similarly, but better.

Comment: It looks like you just want to use a `If` statement - you're not returning anything from your "operator". The conditional operator is supposed to be used as an expression, not a statement.

Comment: Nitpick: a "ternary operator" is just some operator with three operands, just like unary and binary operators have 1 or 2 respectively. You mean the "conditional operator" (which admittedly is the only ternary operator in use)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax to pass Action/Func in VB/Net:

```
TernaryOperater(true, Function() OneArg(42), AddressOf   NoArgs)
```

More info:

First of all to be real "ternary operator" (properly named "conditional operator") you should be using [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) as argument so it can return result.

Method signature you pass as `Func<T>` or `Action<T>` should match the type - function with no arguments and return type T for `Func<T>`, function (sub) with no arguments for `Action<T>`. If it does not match - you can wrap it inline with lambda expression - [lambda expressions in VB.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

C#: 
     int Twice(int value) {return 2 * Value;} 
     int Half(int value) {return 2 * Value;}

```
 T Ternary<T>(bool condition, Func<T> onTrue, Func<T> onFalse) 
 {
     return condition ? onTrue() : onFalse();
 }

 void StrangeIf(bool condition, Action onTrue, Action onFalse) 
 {
     if (condition) 
        onTrue() 
     else 
        onFalse();
 }
 ...

 StrangeIf(true, ignore => Twice(42), ignore => Halhf(42));
 var r = Ternary<int>(true, ignore => Twice(42), ignore => Halhf(42));
```

VB.Net:

```
Function  TernaryOperater(Of T)(condition As Boolean, _
          onTrue As Func(Of T), onFalse As Func(Of T)) As T
    If condition Then
        return onTrue()
    Else
        return onFalse()
    End If
End Function

Sub StrangeIf(condition As Boolean, _
          onTrue As Action, onFalse As Action)
    If condition Then
        onTrue()
    Else
        onFalse()
    End If
End Sub

Function Twice(v as Integer)
    return v * 2
End Function

StrangeIf(true, Function() Twice(42), Function() Twice(1))
```

Comment: Func(of T) is shown under line red error  it's siad Type T is not defined

Comment: @PhattharawitSombatrat I think I've added line you are looking for.